# Sorting array with string data on javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays with string data:

```
var AA = ["~/80/Blue/1.png","~/80/Blue/2.png","~/80/Black/1.png","~/80/Black/2.png"];
var BB = ["~/81/Blue/1.png","~/81/Blue/2.png","~/81/Black/1.png","~/81/Black/2.png"];
```

I need to .concat these arrays and .sort like this:

```
 CC = ["~/80/Blue/1.png","~/81/Blue/1.png","~/80/Blue/2.png","~/81/Blue/2.png","~/80/Black/1.png","~/81/Black/1.png","~/80/Black/2.png","~/81/Black/2.png"];
```

The sort criterion is that I need to have pairs of array elements with same "color directory" and same file name.

I've tried this:

```
var CC = AA.concat(BB);
CC.sort (function(a,b) {
    var Mask = /\W\w+\W\d\Wpng/;
    var A =[];
    var B = [];
    var s1 = a.toLowerCase();
    var s2 = b.toLowerCase();
    for (var i=0; i<s1.length; i++){
      A.push(s1[i].match(Mask));
    }
    for (var i=0; i<s2.length; i++){
      B.push(s2[i].match(Mask));
    }
    for (var i=0; i<A.length; i++){
      for (var j=0; j<B.length; j++){
        if (A[i] < B[j]) {return -1;};
        if (A[i] > B[j]) {return 1;};
        else {return 0;}
        }
    }
```

Comment: what did you try? Please visit help center to get an advice on asking questions

Comment: Please edit and add to your question itself, so, that it is readable to users

Comment: what is the criteria to sort?

Comment: I need to have pairs one by one of array elemens with same "color directory" and same file name. You can see what it should be in question.

Comment: I don't think this is "sorting"--it is "interleaving", right?

Comment: Is the folder structure always going to be three levels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, concat the two arrays and then sort by using the Arrays.sort method, by passing the desired sorting logic as a sortFunction parameter.

```
var AA = ["~/80/Blue/1.png","~/80/Blue/2.png","~/80/Black/1.png","~/80/Black/2.png"];
var BB = ["~/81/Blue/1.png","~/81/Blue/2.png","~/81/Black/1.png","~/81/Black/2.png"];
var CC = [];


var CC = AA.concat(BB);

function string_split_comparator(a, b) {
   var A_colorFile = a.split('/').splice(2).join('/'); /* Blue/1.png */                
   var B_colorFile = b.split('/').splice(2).join('/');
   var A_directoryNum = a.split('/')[1]; /* 80 */
   var B_directoryNum = b.split('/')[1];
   if(A_colorFile !== B_colorFile){
      return A_colorFile < B_colorFile;
   } else{
      return A_directoryNum < B_directoryNum 
   }

}
CC.sort(string_split_comparator);
```

Comment: A and B are undefined.

Comment: @Vlad: And you mentioned colors sorted in reverse alphabetical order. Was that intentional? I mean, you need "Blue" after "Black" or its reverse?

Comment: @Vlad: Good. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var AA = ["~/80/Blue/1.png","~/80/Blue/2.png","~/80/Black/1.png","~/80/Black/2.png"];
var BB = ["~/81/Blue/1.png","~/81/Blue/2.png","~/81/Black/1.png","~/81/Black/2.png"];
var CC = [];

var longestArr = 0;

if (AA.length > BB.length) {
 longestArr = AA.length;
} else {
 longestArr = BB.length;
}

    for (var i = 0; i < longestArr; i++) {
      if (AA[i]!==undefined) {
        CC.push(AA[i]);
      };
      if (BB[i]!==undefined) {
        CC.push(BB[i]);
      };
    }
```

Is it that what you wanted?

Comment: This will leave some undefineds at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to *zip* two arrays of equal length.

```
var CC = AA.reduce(function(result, value, i) {
    return result.concat(value, BB[i]);
}, []);
```

**JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/uh0q2eqb/**

Here's how to sort the arrays of equal length based on directory name and filename as a string, and then zip them.

```
AA.sort(comparator);
BB.sort(comparator);

var CC = AA.reduce(function(result, value, i) {
    return result.concat(value, BB[i]);
}, []);

function comparator(a, b) {
  var A = a.split('/').splice(2).join('/');
  var B = b.split('/').splice(2).join('/');

  if (A > B) {
    return 1;
  } else if (A < B) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

**JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/uh0q2eqb/1/**